# upload the image on s3 using boto

Tags: python, file-upload, amazon-s3, boto

Here I have an image url. filename is image url

```
def upload(filename, content)
    conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key, aws_secret_key)
    b = Bucket(conn, bucket_name)
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = filename..split('/')[::-1][0]
    k.set_metadata("Content-Type", 'images/jpeg')
    k.set_contents_from_string(content)
    k.set_acl("public-read")
```

It upload things to the S3 but it shows the error:

> `/tmp/t.jpeg` could not be opened, because the associated helper application does not exist. Change the association in your preferences.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? It seems likely to me that your problem may not be in the piece of code you pasted.

Comment: This seems like an error message you get when trying to open the JPEG image in Firefox/Windows. You can always open JPEG images with Windows Photo Viewer. Check that you the application to open *.jpg and *.jpeg files is correctly associated in Firefox or Windows.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure images/jpeg is a typo.  The correct mimetype is:

```
image/jpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

```
k.key = filename..split('/')[::-1][0]
```

This line has some syntax error. replace .. with .

Check your file permission for the image file you are trying to read. From the error message it seems like you, or at least your program don't have read access to that file.